# Display cloning with standard(Windows) display drivers

Tags: windows, display, external-display

Is it possible to clone display on an external monitor in Windows XP only using drivers shipped with Windows? I know, it is possible with drivers shipped by NVIDIA, ATI/AMD or Intel, I know.
But all my efforts led only to enlarging virtual screen to two monitors or to setting the main monitor, but not cloning

Answer (score 0):

From past experience, if you are able to get it to extend your screen to a second monitor (enlarging it), you can **easily change the settings** to achieve a mirror or cloning effect.

To accomplish this, either hit <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and hold it to see a settings menu where you can change the current setup, or go to the Control Panel and change it there.

Answer (score -1):

skip drivers, if you just want to clone, make this a hardware question. vga splitters are whoa cheap ([link text](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=1074788&CatId=467)), and s-video/etc. splitters are also available.